# Magento in Thumbnail Category custom theme

Tags: magento

I am working with the 1.9.2.0 version of Magento in a custom theme, it is running smoothly, what I want and as is the name of the main category rather than the category name.Already I tested several tips right here, and several tutorials on the net. But I can not do it, could guide me where I am going wrong?

1.1. I have this code that displays the categories and sub-categories on the home page: file top.phtml

```
<?php
     Mage::helper('custommenu')->saveCurrentCategoryIdToSession();
     $menuData = Mage::helper('custommenu')->getMenuData();
     extract($menuData);

// ---
$txtLoading = '';
$txtMenu = $this->__('Menu');
$xRtl = $_rtl ? ' rtl' : '';
$wpInitContent = <<<HTML
<div id="custommenu-loading" class="$xRtl">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="parentMenu menu0">
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <span>$txtLoading</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
<div id="custommenu" class="$xRtl" style="display:none;">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="parentMenu menu0">
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <span>$txtLoading</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
<div id="custommenu-mobile" class="$xRtl" style="display:none;">
    <div id="menu-button" onclick="wpMenuButtonToggle()">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
            <span>$txtMenu</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-content" style="display:none;">
        <div id="menu-mobile-loading" class="menu-mobile level0">
            <div class="parentMenu">
                <a href="javascript:;">
                    <span>$txtLoading</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearBoth"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
HTML;
?>
<div class="nav-container" id="wp-nav-container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_WIDTH = <?php echo $_popupWidth; ?>;
var CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_TOP_OFFSET = <?php echo $_popupTopOffset; ?>;
var CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_DELAY_BEFORE_DISPLAYING = <?php echo $_popupDelayBeforeDisplaying; ?>;
var CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_DELAY_BEFORE_HIDING = <?php echo $_popupDelayBeforeHiding; ?>;
var CUSTOMMENU_RTL_MODE = <?php echo $_rtl; ?>;
var CUSTOMMENU_MOBILE_MENU_WIDTH_INIT = <?php echo $_mobileMenuWidthInit; ?>;
var wpCustommenuTimerShow = {};
var wpCustommenuTimerHide = {};
var wpActiveMenu = null;
var wpMobileMenuEnabled = <?php echo $_mobileMenuEnabled; ?>;
var wpMenuAjaxUrl = '<?php echo $_menuAjaxUrl; ?>';
var wpMoblieMenuAjaxUrl = '<?php echo $_moblieMenuAjaxUrl; ?>';
var wpPopupMenuContent = '';
var wpMobileMenuContent = '';
if ($('wp-nav-container') != undefined) {
    $('wp-nav-container').update(<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($wpInitContent); ?>);
}
<?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('custom_menu/general/ajax_load_content')) : ?>
wpCustomMenuMobileToggle();
Event.observe(window, 'resize', function() {
    wpCustomMenuMobileToggle();
});
<?php endif; ?>
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Event.observe(document, 'dom:loaded', function(){
    $$('.skip-nav').each(function(element) {
        element.observe('click', function(event) {
            wpMenuButtonToggle();
        });
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

2. Through this code obtained right here on the site can view the images in a category:

> ```
> ** ThumbnailUrl
> $child=Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
> $imageSrc=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($child)->getThumbnail();
> $ThumbnailUrl=Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$imageSrc;
> echo "<img src='{$ThumbnailUrl}' />";
> ```

3. How do I include code in the file list of categories on the home page, all my attempts derão errors?
   Forgive English